# How do I import an already existing git project to gerrit?

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I am using github and want to import a private repo to gerrit so that when I make changes through gerrit it will update the project on github

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you must not push any changes to Github by yourself. If the is OK for you, the replication plugin offers such functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gerrit as a review tool, not as the repository of record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874078/gerrit-as-a-review-tool-not-as-the-repository-of-record)

Answer (score 0):

1) Login into gerrit.
2) Click **github**(left side) and select **repositories**
3) Under **Select GitHub repositories to clone and replicate** , enable the checklist to import the project, you need from git